# Swift 3 Writing to Text File

Tags: ios, swift

In my application, I am trying to add data to a text file in the document directory of the program called saveURL.txt so it can later be called and parsed. I have my code being

```
let fileName = "saveURL"
let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt")
print("FilePath: \(fileURL.path)")

let writeString = "Write this text to the fileURL as text in iOS using Swift"
do {
    // Write to the file
    try writeString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print("past try writeString.write")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

var readString = "" // Used to store the file contents
do {
    // Read the file contents
    readString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
print("File Text: \(readString)")
```

The output displayed in the console is

> FilePath: /Users/mike/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/752A5025-0AA0-4BE1-B70F-644A904F2D8A/data/Containers/Data/Application/0084AD99-63DB-439F-8427-DDDF161CFAC0/Documents/saveURL.txt
>   past try writeString.write
>   File Text: Write this text to the fileURL as text in iOS using Swift

Which is displaying output that it was infact stored, but when I go to check the file to see if it was actually appended to it, it is still blank. I've read all over that the swift files are meant to be read only and such but i've also seen examples that work but not in my program.

Comment: Please update your question (don't post comments) with the actual output of the `print` statements in the code you posted.

Comment: What do you mean by *"when I go to check the file to see if it was actually appended to it, it is still blank"*? How are you checking? What is blank?

Comment: The saveURL file in my program file directory is still an empty text file even though it is being written too apparently. I am checking just my checking the file and clicking on it to see if it contains anything

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for write url in your text file.

```
func writeToFile(urlString: String)
{
    let file = "/saveURL.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

        if let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true).first {
        let path = dir + file
        print(path)
        do {
            try urlString.write(toFile: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I implemented this function and I have it being called when a save button is pressed, passing the string to the function. It does get successfully called but when I check my actual saveURL.txt file inside my program, there is no text written to it still.

Comment: I have update this 'print(path)' in answer please check on that path

Comment: `/Users/mike/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/752A5025-0AA0-4BE1-B70F-644A904F2D8A/data/Containers/Data/Application/A1895394-2AFF-41DE-A174-45F7A8B77258/Documents/saveURL.txt` Is what comes up when I print it out

Comment: In Finder->Go To Folder->paste this path->Go
now you can see this file

Comment: That does show a path containing many many files but is there any possible way to write to the txt file that I located in my application so it can be stored or no? It is starting to seem like no haha

Comment: it's path to your application directory. it's store in the application.

Comment: How does this answer help? Explain what is wrong in the question and how this answer fixes that problem. And why would you use `NSString` in this Swift code?